# Bootstrapp Affix Function

Tags: javascript, css, django, django-bootstrap3, django-bootstrap4

If I copy the code from W3Schools to my webserver then the "sticky" menu works as long as I am referencing the CDN path for the script and 
stylesheet.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

If I change it to the location of the Bootstrap files that I have downloaded to the server then it doesn't work, although all other bootstrap
styles and javascript functions work when referencing the local files. I have tried downloading the latest from Bootstrap as well.

Sorry as I am probably missing something obvious, but is it possible to download the function and styles necessary for this to work?

Comment: Can you provide the code-snippet where you try to load the resources from your local files?

Answer (score 1):

i suggest try this: first you need set your static files in this case Bootstrap(css, js, etc):

```
static
....Bootstrap
......CSS
.........bootstrap.min.css
......JS
.........jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js
.........popper.min.js
.........bootstrap.min.js
....etc
..etc
```

in this case we has the posible structure folder for static into this folder put the folder that content css an js files of bootstrap.
the next is set your links for css and js files in you template similar to this:

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'Bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css' %}">

    <title>Hello, world!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Hello, world!</h1>

    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="{% static 'Bootstrap/js/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'Bootstrap/js/popper.min.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'Bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js' %}"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

now you need this on your settings.py:

```
..
..
..
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
    '/static/',
]
...
..
```

that is all for load bootstrap or other static files in yout template, please try and good luck.

For download Bootstrap4 , 3..etc.. go to the official website:

[Official site Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/getting-started/introduction/)

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I will take a another look and let you know. I think that my static files are set up in this way though and I have the same calls apart from "popper.min.js". Static files are being picked up as I have used them elsewhere in my templates.

Comment: I need to download popper as I didn't originally have this.

Comment: here..download....."https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"

Comment: Thanks, I will hopefully try this soon and let you know.

Comment: Hi, I have tried adding the popper library and that doesn't work. I didn't think it would because it is not being referenced. It seems to be isolated to the bootstrap js and the bootstrap CSS because if I take out the static ones and replace with the CDN ones then it works. I have downloaded the latest ones.